# PHP create Url in mysqli_query while loop for every record

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a link within a while loop where the anchor link is a record from the query and the href passes a variable from the same query to another page so I only have to create one page that displays information based on the passed variable.

```
echo "<td>";
echo '<a href="stats_game.php?idGame=.$row['idGame']">'$row['result']'</a>'';
echo "</td></tr>";
```

This link kills my page and return an error.

Comment: you have errors in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td>";
echo '<a href="stats_game.php?idGame='.$row['idGame'].'">'.$row['result'].'</a>';
echo "</td></tr>";
```

Should fix your code your quotes are not closed right

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I must have walked over that a thousand times.

Answer (score 1):

Your `href` string concatenation is incorrect.

It seems like you tried closing your strings and concatenating them halfway through and then stopped. Even with Stack Overflow you can see the string errors.

This is how your `href` `echo` should look:

```
echo '<a href="stats_game.php?idGame=' .$row['idGame'] . '>' . $row['result'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me

```
echo "<td><a href='stats_game.php?idGame=".$row['idGame']."'>".$row['result']."</a></td>";
```